# Render RHTML inside RHTML Ruby (Like PHP Include)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey people sorry it this seems stupid! I usually code in PHP so this is very different! In PHP I would write...

```
<?php include 'somefile.php'; ?>
```

Now in ruby I have my `.rhtml` which contain instances of `<%= Something %>` and `<% something %>` I have two RHTML files one.html and two.rhtml How to I render one within another? I'm not trying to render scripts just plain HTML inside a .rhtml file type.

I have tried `<% include('two.rhtml');%>` as in http://www.phptoruby.com/tag/include

could someone give my some guidance ?

Many many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using

```
render products/show
```

where show will be a partial.

Referring to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html would help.
Explanation:

In one.rhtml code will be as follwos:

here assumption is that one.rhtml and two.rhtml are in the same folder of views. If there are in different folder you will like to mention the path like <%= render products/show %> where _show.rhtml is being called from product's folder of views.

Remember that partial files are named as _show.rhtml, _.html.erb

Comment: Thanks for this. Do i need to define elsewhere where the products view folders are? or is it just products in relation to where one.rhtml is?

Answer (score 2):

You have to render a partial
[Rails Partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

You have to save the file that you want to call with an **_**(underscore) like **_two.html.erb** and then call that partial in one.html.erb with

```
render "two"
```

I usually create a folder for the partials, for example I create a folder called *partials* inside **app/views** and inside *partials* I create the partials I need, then call them with

```
render "partials/partial_name"
```

Comment: Odd, this is giving me errors. How do i diagnose errors in rhtml files?

Comment: Can you check changing the files to extension html.erb?, I think new version of rails doesn't support rhtml anymore